# Maximization of sum of functions

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $w,a\in R^n$, and $B\in R^{n\times n}_{++}$ (the set of $n\times n$ positive definite matrices).

We know that the following function (which is a specific form of the Rayleigh quotient) has a unique maximum, and a closed-form solution in $w$:

$$f(w)=\frac{w^Taa^Tw}{w^TBw}$$

It's maximum is achieved at $w^*=B^{-1}a$ and its value is $f(w^*)=a^TB^{-1}a$. (by using the generalized eigenvalue decomposition)

Now here is my question:

If I have $w,a_1,a_2\in R^n$, and $B_1,B_2\in R^{n\times n}_{++}$, and the following function:

$$g(w)=\frac{w^Ta_1a_1^Tw}{w^TB_1w}+\frac{w^Ta_2a_2^Tw}{w^TB_2w}$$

Then, what can we say about the maximum of $g(w)$, can we still solve for $w$ in closed-form?

Thanks!

Comment: Let $a=(1,0)$, $B=I_{2\times 2}$. Then $f(x,y)=x^2/(x^2+y^2)$ is concave in $(x,y)$?

Comment: @Rahul: Thanks! That was a mistake, I meant it has a unique maximum (, and a closed-form solution). I fixed it.

Comment: If you say so. But the maximum can't be unique because $f(\alpha w)=f(w)$ for all $\alpha\ne0$.

Comment: sure, I mean up to scaling. We can assume $w^Tw=1$  (and normalize the closed-form solution accordingly) (good point). But the maximum value itself doesn't change.

Comment: @Rahul: By the way, by "maximum" I mean the maximum value, not the the solution point in which the maximum is achived; as you said the maximum is unique: $f(w)=f(\alpha w)~~\forall \alpha\neq 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The maximum is reached in points $w$ s.t.

$\dfrac{(a_1^Tw)}{w^TB_1w}a_1+\dfrac{(a_2^Tw)}{w^TB_2w}a_2=\dfrac{(a_1^Tw)^2}{(w^TB_1w)^2}B_1w+\dfrac{(a_2^Tw)^2}{(w^TB_2w)^2}B_2w$. In the unknown $w$, it is an homogeneous equation of degree $7$, and consequently, can only be numerically solved.

EDIT 1. Multiplying on the left the previous equation by $w^T$, we obtain an identity.

EDIT 2. You can use the Newton's method, adding the conditions $w^Tw=1,w_1>0$. Yet, you must give a good initial estimate, otherwise the sequence does not converge! This is difficult, especially when the system has many solutions. Unfortunately, this happens here. Indeed, generically, when $n=2$, there are $2$ real solutions and, when $n=3$, $5$ real solutions. If $n$ is great, then it may exist many candidates. I see only one case where the choice is easy; that is when $B_1^{-1}a_1$ and $B_2^{-1}a_2$ are close.

Comment: Thanks. How do we know that the maximum is reached at w s.t.: $$\dfrac{(a_1^Tw)}{w^TB_1w}a_1+\dfrac{(a_2^Tw)}{w^TB_2w}a_2=\dfrac{(a_1^Tw)^2}{(w^TB_1w)^2}B_1w+\dfrac{(a_2^Tw)^2}{(w^TB_2w)^2}B_2w$$?

Comment: Because $\nabla f(w)=\dfrac{(a^Tw)}{w^TBw}a-\dfrac{(a^Tw)^2}{(w^TBw)^2}Bw$.

Comment: Thanks, what numerical method do you think fits it best? for example, I can think of power method, gradient decent, etc.?